# Magento 2.3.3 dates change after saving product

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

After upgrading to `2.3.3` the dates are not saved correct.

When I change the product `new from` and `to date` and then save it, the date is messed up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We have been through this. we migrated from M1 to M2. Notice Magento 2 does not handle these dates any longer.

[image: Dates]

Since I located these attributes with id 94 and 95:

[image: Attribute ids]

Run this query in your DB

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime`  WHERE attribute_id IN (94,95)
```

Nullify those dates from DB and reenter again from admin and then save. It won't mess up.

Let me know if this works for you, too.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! But not working :-(

Comment: Dates are correct in DB, so there has to be some fault in thanslation in PHP to admin

Comment: When adding new product the problem also stays

Comment: Figured out that it is the localisation, when i switch to english/US the problem is gone. When go back to dutch it is there again. Now searching for solution